# How do i uncheck "Use Lambda Proxy Integration" in an API Gateway method from with SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I'm trying to work my way through AWS sam and setting up a new ApiGateway. I want the lambdas to run without the 'use lambda proxy integration' setting. I've been trying for ages now, and haven't made much progress.

A simplified version of my template.yaml

```
Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      #snip#
      Events:
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /Some/Path
            Method: Post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: MyApi

  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: Some-Api
      StageName: Prod
```

As you can see, I haven't made any progress at all. I'm simply getting lost in the configuration here, and hoping that anyone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Sicne you have opted out of integration proxy, the request and response may need mapping.

Have you tried updating the integration response - mapping template, try below,

```
 AWS::Serverless::Api
       GatewayResponses
```

[image]